# Dropdown Menu on Home button click ActionBarSherlock xamarin

Tags: c#, android, actionbarsherlock

I want a dropdown menu when the user clicks the home button on the ActionBar. Something like below:-

[image]

I have tried using a Spinner like so:-

```
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.IMenuItem item)
        {
            // Click events for ActionBar items
            switch(item.ItemId)
            {
                // Home (Top left corner) 
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:

                    var  mspinner = new Spinner(this);
                    ArrayList mSpinnerOptions = new ArrayList();
                    mSpinnerOptions.Add("Stay");

                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, mSpinnerOptions);
                    mspinner.Adapter = adapter;

                    ActionBar.SetCustomView(mspinner);

                    break;
}
```

But it gives me an error when I try to `SetCustomView`.

```
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'Android.App.ActionBar.SetCustomView(int)' has some invalid arguments
```

Edit:-

I tried something like below:-

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
                View mCustomeView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.spinnerlayout, null);

                Spinner mspinner = mCustomeView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.home_spinner);
                ArrayList mSpinnerOptions = new ArrayList();
                mSpinnerOptions.Add("Stay");

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, mSpinnerOptions);
                mspinner.Adapter = adapter;

                ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
                ActionBar.SetCustomView(mCustomeView, null);
```

But still get the same error

Comment: You can also try this `if(mspinner == null) { Log.v("Test", "Is null"}` Maybe, your FindViewById has returned null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this statement:

```
var  mspinner = new Spinner(this);
```

to:

```
Spinner  mspinner = new Spinner(this);
```

It's going to inform the compiler that you are creating a Spinner object.

Comment: Try this code: `Log.v("Test", mspinner.getClass());` It's going to print in the Logcat which class the mspinner variable is associated to.

Comment: I can do the same if i do it in Java. The error says that I need to pass a int value to SetCustomView

Comment: You can either pass an int variable or a View object to the setCustomView method. Look in the documentation, it's going to help you. I strongly suggest you to declare the object `Spinner` the way I showed you.

Comment: I Changed it to "Spinner" now and it still gives me the same error. Also I tried passing a Viwe object but doesnt help either

Comment: You need to figure out why the mspinner argument is invalid. You should try `Log.v("Test", mspinner.getClass());` to see what the `getClass();` method returns on your object.